# Strange behavior of a Pivot Slicer in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to set a slicer with specific conditions. The problem is that I can't set it as a variable to further go down into it's `.SlicerItems`

```
Sub SetSlicers(ByVal peer_wrk, ByVal slic_name As String, ByVal slic_condition As Variant)

    Dim sl_item, sl_dummy As SlicerItem
    Dim sl_box As SlicerCache
    
    
    For Each sl_box In peer_wrk.SlicerCaches
        Debug.Print (sl_box.Name)
    Next

    Set sl_box = peer_wrk.SlicerCaches(slic_name)
```

I'm passing workbook into this subroutine and the slicer name as string. Interestingly, when I loop through slicers in the workbook I can see the one I pass an argument is showing up with exactly same name but the `Set sl_box = peer_wrk.SlicerCaches(slic_name)` fails to execute and returns the following error:

[image: Error MSG]

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `Debug.Print sl_box.name, sl_box.name = slic_name` - maybe there is a blank or whatever so there is no match

Comment: You should specify the type for 'peer_wrk'.  At the moment it is implicitly variant which means you won't get any help from the inteliisense in the for statement.  If you haven't done so already, please download and install the free and fantastic Rubberduck Addin for VBA and take a look at the code inspections.

Comment: @freeflow you were right, specifying 'peer_wrk' as Workbook helped. My intuition though was that I don't have to do that since it's already specified in the sub from which I call that specific subroutine and it takes exactly the same type. Well, I was wrong then. Thanks!